# Formatting Math as Text

Tags: formatting, ascii

I usually use *roff or LaTeX for Math writing when outputting PDF. For writing Math on Canvas, email or other platforms, it seems to be more convenient to format Math using only ASCII. Is there a standard way to format Math as text?

Comment: Welcome, your LaTeX input is just plain text, right?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I usually write in tex, eqn (in Groff) for plain text but I also wonder it there is a standard that is most acceptable.

Comment: Think about how you write math in a programming language. Non of it is formatted, but you understand the meaning. Same for LaTeX input code. All just with ASCII. If you want formatted math as text, you should look at the full unicode spectrum. But that isn't ASCII anymore.

Comment: That's a good consideration. I also think that because a lot of these mark-up tags or makers are from the macros or preprocessors for TeX or Troff but they aren't the base of the languages itself. Would that be widely acceptable?

Comment: most people  just write latex source fragments, but there is a Unicode Technical Note TN28 for plain text mathematics https://www.unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v3.1.pdf  But this is essentially Microsoft Office "linear format" math so not widely implemented outside MS Office.

Comment: You could use https://github.com/tomtung/latex2unicode (live demo at http://latex2unicode.herokuapp.com/) but many things like integral limits or even a broad range of sub- and superscripts are not properly supported by Unicode.

Comment: Thank you all for the ideas and advice!

Comment: In vim, you could use [vim-unicoder](https://github.com/arthurxavierx/vim-unicoder)